# How do I sample a pandas dataframe based on observations from 5 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I have a dataframe of sells for five years at the daily level, across 658 different items.

Each item is a part of it's own unique product hierarchy.  So, eye liner is a part of:

1. Beauty
2. COLOR COLLECTIONS COLLECTIONS-EYE
3. EYE COLOR
4. ARTISTRY
5. SIGNATURE COLOR

Each product has it's own path through the hierarchy.  That said, I'd like to sample five products from all paths of the hierarchy then use those items to filter down my dataframe.

I was thinking of making another column of each item's hierarchy concatenated together so I have a single column to group items by.  I'm not sure where to go from there.

Is there a way to do this in python?

Comment: You could do that and use [sample()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html) on the groupby

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out as RJ alluded to:

```
import random
df['hierarchy_group'] = df['GLBL_BUS_LN_DESC']+"_"+df['GLBL_CTGRY_DESC']+"_"+df['GLBL_SUB_CTGRY_DESC']+"_"+df['GLBL_PRDCT_IND_CUT_DESC']+"_"+df['GLBL_BRAND_DESC']+"_"+df['GLBL_SUB_BRAND_DESC']
h_count = df.groupby(['hierarchy_group']).agg({'ITEM_ROOT':'nunique'}).reset_index().sort_values('ITEM_ROOT')
h_dict = dict(zip(h_count['hierarchy_group'], h_count['ITEM_ROOT']))
h_groups = list(df['hierarchy_group'].unique())
samples = []
for k, v in h_dict.items():
    df_ = df.copy()
    df_ = df_[df_['hierarchy_group']==k]
    item_list = list(df_['ITEM_ROOT'].unique())
    sample_list = random.sample(item_list,1)
    for i in sample_list:
        samples.append(i)
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to accomplish this but it seems to work.